# Why cant I parse this JSON output using shell/python?

Tags: json, python-2.7, shell

Here is the output from the response I am trying to parse:

```
[{"name":"UsedMemory","value":{"value":"35054384","type":"java.lang.Long"}},
{"name":"FreeMemory","value":{"value":"7085264","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"Heap","value":{"value":"42139648","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"UpTime","value":{"value":"3350544","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"ProcessCPU","value":{"value":"0.3625301325982962","type":"java.lang.Double"}},{"name":"GcCount","value":{"value":"224","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"GcTime","value":{"value":"335","type":"java.lang.Long"}}]
```

I am storing the response in a shell variable called $jvmStats and expect to be able to retrieve a value from it based on name like this:

```
$jvmStats | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['UsedMemory']"
```

but the response I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Pretty new to working with JSON and unfortunately don't have the ability to use jq on this system - can some one point out the problem to me? This seems like a fairly standard approach according to all the other answers I see here - so perhaps nested value parts is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
jvmStats | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)[0]['name']"
```

This is because your JSON is first a list and then a dictionary, so you need to index the list first and then the key of the dictionary.

Also, you can only index JSON by its key, not its value.

Comment: looks better - thanks! Beginning to see that the format is inconsistent with what I want to achieve via python. I essentially want a one liner to output a  bunch of k=v pairs. I am not the provider of the JSON and there is no guarantee there lines will come out in the same order each time - thus doing things by indices is going to be tough. I am probably better with a sed command!